# C/C++ timer, like Swiss watches

Tags: c++, c, timer

Can someone provide a list of timers for C/C++ that they provide god level accuracy?

If for example I take 100 computers and start the program at the same microsecond in all of them, I want the timers to display the same time on all computers (with different CPUs and different CPU loads) after a year of continuously running.

**Platform**: Linux
**Accuracy**: 1 second but the timer must be EXACLTY 1 second, not 1 second and 1/1000000. this extra 1/1000000 is not acceptable. In other words, in one year of running, not even a second of lost accuracy is acceptable.

**The timer must not need extra hardware.**

**Q1**: What's the best timer the mankind made and it's free (chrono, setitimer, the one of the many boost timers, or something else?)

**Q2:**: Using this best timer, what kind of accuracy I can expect, when using an Ivy Bridge CPU?

Comment: There's http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/ but on top of that you won't anything more precise. If 1 Computer has a 1 second hardware problem you'll be off. A program can only do so much.

Comment: In a perfect world, without hardware and software bugs, will the timers be accurate, or the CPU load (if it's 100%) will put them off?

Comment: No timer in the world will give you exactly one second. You always have to specify an accuracy. If 1ppm is not acceptable for you, then commodity PC hardware seems to be out of the question.

Comment: Accurate timers are a factor of your platform's processors, not software.

Comment: @FiddlingBits It's both actually!! The one thing is how your OS exposes time to your client process, the othe might involve using precise HW timers directly from your client process.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right... you could write some crappy timer interrupt handlers.

Comment: @Blazer Are you sure this isn't an advertisement for Swiss watches? ;-)

Comment: All in all, what kind of accuracy will I lose in a year using normal computers?

Comment: You can program your software not to lose accuracy, however it is dependent on your hardware clock

Comment: What you're asking is silly.  Any advice given would require a year of testing before you'd know if it was good according to your requirements.

Comment: you are right, but using mathematical calculations you can see what kind of accuracy you will lose. The Wikipedia page says the times loses accuracy in one per million years, so they didn't test it for a million years but they know the accuracy :P

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yeah, you'd need manufacturing calibration and self calibration.

Comment: @Blazer Doubt your PC has an atomic clock. ;-)

Comment: can i add this thing as usb like people add random password generators?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement.  First you say the time must be *exactly* the same after 1 year, then you talk about "accuracy... must be EXACTLY 1 second" and "in one year of running, not even a second of lost accuracy is acceptable".  Obviously if 1 second is the maximum error tolerance in 1 year you wouldn't expect *exactly* one second of error, though you might say that's the absolute maximum error tolerable.  What is it you really want?  You're measuring elapsed time of what exactly?  Will your CPUs use frequency scaling or suspend/sleep modes?

Comment: I am sorry, my English are not good enough. I want a perfect in terms of accuracy timer. If that's not possible I want to know what kind of accuracy the timer I will use will have.

Comment: @Blazer You're going to have to sync with something external.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best timing accuracy you can get with your program is synchronizing with an [atomic clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock) device, like the [USNO Master Clock](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/time/master-clock/).

/sarcasm off

To give a few hints:

1. The C++ standard doesn't guarantee anything beyond milliseconds accuracy, and even these might end up in tenths of ms jittering (depends on OS).
2. Your hardware timers might provide better accuracy, but your drivers/applications still might introduce unwanted latencies
3. If you're really going to get nearly precise for your requirements, don't forget to keep in mind compensation of relativistic effects like height position, speed, etc. of the measurement equipment

> **Q2:** Using this best timer, what kind of accuracy I can expect, when using an Ivy Bridge CPU?

Multiples of nanoseconds I'd guess, if done right (forget about that atomic clock joke when going to this direction).

Comment: Atomic clock... Makes me want to go into science just to create one of my own using a different timing. /drool

Comment: I believe that the US Navy has handed over the responsibility of keeping the nation's official time to NIST. After many years when my computers called up tick or tock once a week.